# Getting "null" from String Method [java]

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a a method that combines the first and last name variables to create a fullName variable but I keep getting null whenever instead of the full name? I'm not getting any actual errors so I don't know where it's going wrong?

```
  @Override

 public String toString() {
    return String.format("%-22s  %.2f  %-4s  %s", fullName, gpa, major, year);

  }

  public void setfirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  public String getfirstName() {
    return firstName;

  }

  public void setlastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }

  public String getlastName() {
    return lastName;

  }
public void setfullName(String fullName) {
    fullName = (lastName + ", " + firstName);
  }

  public String getfullName() {
    return fullName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your fullname is a local variable inside the following method.

```
public void setfullName(String fullName) {
    fullName = (lastName + ", " + firstName);
}
```

Just make it an attribute of the object and user **this.fullname** to assign the full name.Also there's no point in passing parameters to setFullName() method, since what you are doing is concatenating first name and the last name.

```
public void setfullName() {
    this.fullName = (lastName + ", " + firstName);
}
```

Therefore instead of using a setFullName() method, you can only use getFullName() method as follows.

```
public String getfullName() {
    return lastName + ", " + firstName;
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting 'null'. I had tried just the getfullName method initially but it gave me null which is why i assumed I needed the setter, any idea why it's doing it?

Comment: because you don't have an attribute called firstName in the class. Even though there is, in the setFullName method, you have another variable in the same name,which is local. You are assigning to that local variable. TO assign the class variable, use this.fullName.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused, where exactly am I suppose to use this.fullname? Within one of the firstName methods or within the toString?

Comment: @HiImIsabella It should be inside of setfullName.

Comment: @PufanJiang I thought I was suppose to use only the getFullName and the set method?

Comment: But, in this case, you are not actually setting the full name. Instead, you join the first name and the last name. Therefore, there's no need of having a set full name method. Setters (set method) are used when you actually setting a value by passing on a parameter. in this case you are not setting a value, even though you pass on a parameter.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha so when I use fullName in the toString method, the reason I'm getting "null" is because getfullName() never actually makes a fullName variable right? Wouldn't I have to make it fullName = lastName + firstName to declare it?

Comment: yes. Or you can do something better like, in the toString() method, you can call the getFirstName() method instead of the firstName attribute. return String.format("%-22s  %.2f  %-4s  %s", getFullName(), gpa, major, year);

Comment: Okay adding the getfullName() is what ended up doing, thank you!